# Let $X~Bin(n, \lambda/n)$, $\lambda >0$. Show that for fixed $k \geq 0$, $P(X=k)\equiv \frac{e^-\lambda)\lambda^k}{k!}$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, exponential-sum

Let $X - Bin(n, \lambda/n)$, $\lambda >0$. By using approximation $(1-\frac{x}{n})^n\approx e^{-x}$. Show that for fixed $k\geq 0$, $P(X=k)\approx \frac{e^{-\lambda}\lambda^k}{k!}$

---

$P(X=k)=\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}(\frac{\lambda}{n})^k(1-\frac{\lambda}{n})^{n-k}=\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}\frac{(\frac{\lambda}{n})^k}{(1-\frac{\lambda}{n})^k}(1-\frac{\lambda}{n})^n\approx\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}\frac{(\frac{\lambda}{n})^k}{(1-\frac{\lambda}{n})^k}e^{-\lambda}$

Where do I got from here?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Use $$\frac{n!}{(n-k)!} = n(n-1)\dots(n-k+1) = n^k(1+o(1))\approx n^k$$ and $$
\big(1-\frac{\lambda}{n}\big)^k = 1+o(1) \approx 1.
$$

Comment: What does the notation $o(1)$ denote?

Otherwise, makes perfect sense.

Comment: $o(1)$ means "going to 0."